# Creating a custom codeigniter validation rule

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I have a function in my login form that checks if the email and password match the values in the database and if so it logs the user into the system.

I would like to display a validation error if this function returns false.

My problem is that I am unsure how to go about creating this. The message relates to both the password and email fields so I would not want a rule for each input field just display a single message.

I have tried using flashdata to achieve this but it only works when the page has been refreshed.

How can I created a new validation rule solely for the function `$this->members_model->validate_member()` ??

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', '"Email address"', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', '"Password"', 'trim|required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $viewdata['main_content'] = 'members/login';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $viewdata);
        }
        else
        {       
                if($this->members_model->validate_member())
                {
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You use the `callback_`  in your rules, see [**callbacks**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks), for ex.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', '"Email address"', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_validate_member');
```

and add the method in the controller. This method needs to return either TRUE or FALSE

```
function validate_member($str)
{
   $field_value = $str; //this is redundant, but it's to show you how
   //the content of the fields gets automatically passed to the method

   if($this->members_model->validate_member($field_value))
   {
     return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
     return FALSE;
   }
}
```

You then need to create a corresponding error in case the validation fails

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('validate_member','Member is not valid!');
```

Comment: @Ivan It's not necessary, but can add on readability, thank you

Comment: May not be necessary, but a leading underscore will prevent the method from being accessible via "/controller_name/validate_member/blah" ... and using a double-underscore is perfectly acceptable IMO "callback__validate_member" ;)

Comment: +1 for the double underscore __ scheme for naming callback functions, as then the functions become inaccessible and return 404. More so, because `private` functions are not working for callbacks.

Answer (score 12):

One best way to achieve this is extending CodeIgniter’s Form Validation library. Let say we want to create a custom validator named `access_code_unique` for the field `access_code` of the database table `users`.

All you have to do is creating a Class file named `MY_Form_validation.php` in `application/libraries` directory. The method should always return `TRUE` OR `FALSE`

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
            // reference to the CodeIgniter super object
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function access_code_unique($access_code, $table_name) {
        $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('access_code_unique', $this->CI->lang->line('access_code_invalid'));

        $where = array (
            'access_code' => $access_code
        );

        $query = $this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table_name, $where);
        return $query->num_rows() === 0;
    }
}
```

Now you can easily add your new created rule

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('access_code', $this->lang->line('access_code'), 'trim|xss_clean|access_code_unique[users]');
```