# regex_match codeigniter length

Tags: regex, codeigniter

I cant seem to find anything in the code igniter documentation about this but I am trying to set a length validation in my form, is this possible?

```
regex_match[/^[0-9().-]+$/]
```

this is for phone numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
^[0-9().-]{n,m}$
```

where n=minimum and m=maximum length.

You may omit the maximum to specify just a minimum, ie

```
^[0-9().-]{n,}$
```

or omit the minimum to specify just a maximum, ie

```
^[0-9().-]{,m}$
```

but this is the same as `^[0-9().-]{0,m}$` so it's not as helpful as the minimum-only version.

Comment: You can also do {,m} to do upto m matches and {m} to get exactly m.

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work `required|regex_match[/^[0-9().-]+$/]{,18}`

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('homephone', 'Home Phone', 'required|regex_match[/^[0-9().-]+$/]{,18}|xss_clean');

Comment: you have the braces **outside** the regex! Do this: `regex_match[/^[0-9().-]{,18}$/]`

Comment: Define "didn't work". Did you get a regex parse error, or was it the input did/didn't match when you expected it to? Note that I don't know codeignighter syntax, so I can't help there. I do know regex well though, and this is a correct regex

Comment: i entered in a number 555.555.5555 and it said it was not the right format

Comment: please give an example of phone number view

Comment: what do u mean? the number 555.555.5555 should work with that expression

Answer (score 1):

You can do as refered in this answer: [Creating a custom codeigniter validation rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181779/creating-a-custom-codeigniter-validation-rule). And then use regular php regex to validate.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
    `regex_match[/^[0-9.-]{0,18}+$/]`