# CodeIgniter num_rows() not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok I don't know what's not working. I know my form validation is definitely working because all my other functions work properly, but I am setting messages whether it's true OR false and none of them show up so I feel like it's skipping right over the validation rule.. which is weird...

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('region', 'required|valid_region');
```

The rule in MY_Form_validation.php in my libraries folder. The library IS loaded first. As I said all my other validations work properly such as my reCaptcha and everything.

```
function valid_region($str) {
        $this->load->database();
        if($this->db->query('SELECT id
                FROM region
                WHERE name = ?
                LIMIT 1', array($str))->num_rows() == 0) {
            //not a valid region name
            $this->set_message('valid_region', 'The %s field does not have a valid value!');
            return false;
        }

        $this->set_message('valid_region', 'Why is it validating?');
    }
```

None of the messages will set so I have a feeling nothing is validating!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181779/creating-a-custom-codeigniter-validation-rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`set_rules()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules) function takes 3 parameters

> 1. The field name - the exact name you've given the form field.
> 2. A "human" name for this field, which will be inserted into the error message.
>      For example, if your field is named "user" you might give it a human
>      name of "Username". Note: If you would like the field name to be
>      stored in a language file, please see Translating Field Names.
> 3. The validation rules for this form field.

You put the validation rules as second parameter. That is why the validation is not running. Try this instead:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('region', 'Region', 'required|valid_region');
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('region', 'required|valid_region');
```

try

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('region', 'required|callback_valid_region');
```

when using custom validation rules you should use

**callback** to prepend the function name.

**UPDATE**

and use

```
$this->form_validation->set_message
```

instead of

```
$this->set_message
```

and in `function valid_region`

use `return true` when validation is successfull

Comment: @Peanut is extending the core validation class and the validation function has been declared in the extended class `MY_Form_validation`. So he doesn't have to prepend the function name with `callback_`

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('region', 'Region', 'required|valid_region');

function valid_region() {
    $str = $this->input->post('name_of_input');
    $this->load->database();
    if($this->db->query('SELECT id
            FROM region
            WHERE name = ?
            LIMIT 1', array($str))->num_rows() == 0) { // why compare "=" between `name` field and array() ?
        //not a valid region name
        $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_region', 'The %s field does not have a valid value!');
        return false;
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_region', 'Why is it validating?');
    return true;
}
```